# Displaying last record after insertion c#

Tags: c#, sql

I read upon a document on how to retrieve the last record after inserted. However when I do, nothing gets filled on the datagridview. This is what I have.

```
 static String connectionString = @"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename= C:\Users\home\Documents\C# Programs\program\Database.mdf ;Integrated Security = True";
        private void displayLastInsertedRecord()
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select @@identity", connectionString))
            {
                DataTable table = new DataTable(connectionString);
                dataAdapter.Fill(table);
                employeeDataGridView.DataSource = table;
            }
        }
```

I checked to see if in fact the data is being stored into the database table and it actually is. It just not display factors such as their name, city, address, etc etc.Cannot figure out what I am doing incorrectly.

Comment: Your method doesn't do what its name suggests it does.  It appears to fill the entire datagrid, not display the last record inserted.

Comment: Yes, I am wanting to display each data from the last record inserted into the datagrid. I thought by using `select @@identity` would do so, based on the article I read? Sorry I am very new to this.

Comment: Select @@identity returns the last identity value generated, not the last row inserted.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is returning a single row, single column table, which contains the *Primary Key value* of the last inserted data row, in any table in your database, provided that such primary key is an `IDENTITY` column. Since you want the actual data, change your query from:

`SELECT @@IDENTITY`

to:

`SELECT @LastID = @@IDENTITY; SELECT * FROM [YourTableName] WHERE [YourPrimaryKeyColumn] = @LastID`

where `[YourTableName]` is the table you're interested in getting the inserted row from (must match last insert command, otherwise the returned dataset will either contain no rows, or have an accidentally matching record - basically, garbage data), and `[YourPrimaryKeyColumn]` is the name of the primary key column in the aforementioned table.

Also, consider using [SCOPE_IDENTITY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) or [IDENT_CURRENT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ident-current-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) instead.